# How can I use realm with UITableViewController with my own sorting order?

Tags: uitableview, realm, realm-list

I am currently using Realm with swift. I am using Realm results object to fill up a UITableViewController. The UITableViewController has add/delete capabilities. Right now, all of this works with the RealmResults. But I need to sort the results in a different way. I noticed that there is a Realm List. But if I start adding or deleting objects, do I need to manage the objects myself in the List? With the Realm Query object, it is automatically updated. In my scenario, what would be the best way to solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a great question! Realm Results are auto-updating, and will always reflect the current state of the query, but sorting is limited.

For small data sets, it may be reasonable to provide custom sorting over Results, but the sort will need to be re-applied every time the Results is updated.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  var sortedResults = [Person]()
  var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(Person).filter("age > 5")
    notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] _ in
      self?.sortedResults = results.sort { a, b in
        /* custom sorting here */
        return a > b
      }
      self?.updateUI()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the code sample, I guess this method could work